# Dropdown overlapping mobile

Tags: css

I have made a website with a navigation menu, there are also two dropdown menus that work fine on the desktop. However, on mobile, the drop-down menu 'recruiting' overlaps other menus once clicked.

I have used z index to bring to the front but I don't want the menu to come forward and insisted I want it to push the other menu below it down.{1}

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks")

function showMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "0";
}
function hideMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
}

let click = document.querySelector('.click');

let list = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-1');




document.getElementById('navLinks').onclick = function () {

    var className = ' ' + navLinks.className + ' ';

    this.className = ~className.indexOf(' active ') ?
        className.replace(' active ', ' ') :
        this.className + ' active';
};
click.addEventListener("click", () => {

    list.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-1');
    

});

let click2 = document.querySelector('.click2');

let list2 = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-2');




document.getElementById('navLinks').onclick = function () {

    var className = ' ' + navLinks.className + ' ';

    this.className = ~className.indexOf(' active ') ?
        className.replace(' active ', ' ') :
        this.className + ' active';
};
click2.addEventListener("click", () => {

    list2.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-2');


});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background:royalblue;
}

.Header {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(Images/Home.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
}
nav{
    display:flex;
    padding: 2% 2% 0 2%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}

nav img{
    width:9rem;

}
.banner img {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 8% 0% 0% 0%;
}
.nav-Links {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

    .nav-Links ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: relative;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
    }


.nav-Links ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-Links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: royalblue;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-Links ul li:hover::after{
    width:100%;
}

.Header-Text {
    width: 90%;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8% 0% 0% 0%
}
.Header-Text h1{
    font-size:60px;

}

.Header-Text p {
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
    font-size:25px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

.Button{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid white;
    padding:12px 34px;
    font-size:20px;
    background: transparent;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.Button:hover{
    border: 1px solid royalblue;
    background:royalblue;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

nav .fas{
    display:none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
    .Header-Text h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .nav-Links ul li {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-Links {
        position: fixed;
        background: royalblue;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        top: 0;
        right: -201px;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    nav .fas {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
        cursor: pointer
    }

    nav {
        display: flex;
        padding: 2% 1%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

        nav img {
            width: 100px;
        }

    .nav-Links ul {
        padding: 20px;
    }

        .nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-1 ul {
            margin-top: -20px;
        }


    .nav-Links ul {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

        .row img {
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top: 5%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;
        }

    .content-table th,
    .content-table td {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    



}




.Sub-Header{
    height:50vh;
    width:100%;   
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

.Sub-Header h1{
    font-size:50px;
}

.About-Us{
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
    padding-top:80px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    
}

.about-col{
    flex-basis:48%;
    padding:30px 2px;
}

.about-col img{
    width:100%;
}

.row {
    margin-top:5%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;  
}


.about-col h1{
    padding-top:0;
}

.About-Col p {
    padding: 15px 0 25px;
    text-align: justify;   
}

.Course{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:100px;
}

h1{
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:600;

}

p{
    color:black;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:22px;
    padding:5px 0px 10px 0px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.Blue{
    border:1px solid royalblue;
    background:transparent;
    color:royalblue;
    font-size:20px;
}

.Blue:hover {
    color: white;
}


.content-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.content-table thead tr {
    background-color: royalblue;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    }

.content-table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.content-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.content-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
     border-bottom: 2px solid royalblue;
}

.content-table tbody tr.active-row {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: royalblue;
}

.Location{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    padding:80px 0;
}

.Location iframe{
    width:100%;
}

.Contact-Us{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
   
}
.Contact-Col {
    flex-basis: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.Contact-Col div{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.Contact-Col div .fas, .far{
    font-size: 40px;
    color:royalblue;
    margin:10px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.Contact-Col div p{
    margin:0;
}

.Contact-Col div h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight:400;
}

.Contact-Col input, .Contact-Col textarea{
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    margin-bottom:17px;
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid royalblue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:royalblue;
}

.Sub-menu-1,
.Sub-menu-2 {
    display: none;
}

.NewSub-menu-1,
.NewSub-menu-2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

    .NewSub-menu-1 ul,
    .NewSub-menu-2 ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        transition: 2s;
    }



.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-1 ul li,
.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-2 ul li {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-left {
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.nav-Links.active .fas.fa-chevron-left {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <title>324SQN - City of Randwick</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
<body>
    <section class="Header">
        
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Logo.png" /></a>
            <a href="index.html" class="banner"><img src="Images/Sologan.png" /></a>

            <div class="nav-Links" id="navLinks">
                <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>

                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="Home.html">Home</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="About.html">About Us</a> </li>
                    <li class="click2">
                        Recruiting  <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

                        <div class="Sub-menu-2">

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>                   

                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="">Leave Request</a> </li>
                    <li  class="click"> CadetLinks  <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

                        <div class="Sub-menu-1">

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Number 3</a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
        </nav>
        <div class="Header-Text">
            <h1>Number 324 (City of Randwick) Squadron</h1>
            <p>Educate, Challenge, Excites</p>
            <a href="" class="Button">Click Here To Know More</a>
        </div>
    </section>

   <script src="Script1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you go in mobile media query remove position absolute and margin-top on the sub-menu. But here i see other serious problem with javascript.

Comment: Yes, I am new to coding, currently trying to simplify and fixed the code for javascript

Comment: Wdym by remove position absolute?, In my media query I haven't written anything about the submenus